# Input and button on the same line with float right

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I didn't found any way to make button and input in the same line with float right.. 
The input should be on the right and button on the left with float right.. 
The only thing I found made the button on the right side and the input in the left side or made the button append to the left of the page..

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the DOM order of the button and the input if you want to float them both right.

HTML -

```
<div>
  <input type="text" class="float-right">
  <button class="float-right">Submit</button>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.float-right {
  float: right;
}
```

[See the codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLYXjY)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to provide a little more information in order to get some assistance on this. If you are using Bootstrap, then there are several classes that can be used to accomplish various layout solutions, but I think a little more information (and a bootply, or codepen, or jsfiddle) would be helpful.

But if you are using bootstrap, here is how to affect the side the button is on relative to the input just using ready made classes in Bootstrap:

http://www.bootply.com/NbDYNuEwGV